# Perpendicular to direction of oscillation, 2D sine wave

Tags: terminology

Is there a word to describe

[image]

"Contour" works for left but not right. "Phase contour"?

Context, above right is real part of a 2D separable Morlet (let's say, left windowed by Gaussian), called "spin down" as its direction of oscillation is down (with increasing x), but it happens to maximize chirp *up* in wavelet transform, so we get "down resonates with up". So something like "contour up maximizes chirp up".

Comment: perpendendicular to direction of oscillation: "transversal", as in EM waves?

Comment: @MarcusMüller That sounds close, but I think "transversal" is used as "perp to _propagation_", meaning parallel to oscillation. I've not found much definitions to support such use.

Comment: You're of course right!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered borrowing the terminology used for water surface waves of crest and/or trough?

[image: Crest and Trough]
Image from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Crest_and_trough&oldid=1071469845)

Comment: Hmm, I guess. Surprised it lacks an exact name though - for one we might want to be sign-agnostic, and "maxima" sounds too general.